# Gridview pager link with pjax

Tags: gridview, yii2, pjax

I'm using pjax in such way:

```
<?php Pjax::begin([
    'id' => 'clients-list',
    'enablePushState' => false,
    'enableReplaceState' => false,
]); ?>
```

And it works fine for url in browser, but replaces links for pagination in my GridView (link to action in my controller which processing ajax requests). How to avoid it?

Comment: What do you mean by "replaces links"? Links trigger Pjax?

Comment: @arogachev general url is client/update but after clicking gridview delete button (in action column) pjax replaces pagination url to delete action and pagination not working properly because it wants to redirect to delete action (don't want to delete records this way!) with pagination parameters

Answer (score 2):

By default, any links inside Pjax container will trigger pjax request.

To avoid it, add `'data-pjax' => 0` attribute to them, and in this case they will be ignored.

Comment: How to add this attribute to yii2 gridview pagination?